# Incorrect values from reading image EXIF Orientation on iOS?

Tags: ios, image, actionscript-3, air, orientation

I am using Exif information to have a correct rotation for an image captured from mobile camera.

In Android version the possible values are 1,3,6,8, and 9.

In iOS, I am using the same code, but getting invalid values like 393216, 196608, 524288, 65536 etc..

I don't understand why there is such a difference ?

Comment: There is a problem in how you're reading the EXIF from your JPEG  bytes. You likely got down-voted for making others have to guess how to help you. Probably editing a few lines in your code could fix this but since none was shown, I could only ramble on below.. hope it helps though. Peace.

Comment: Thank you for this note, but the problem is that my native language is not english .. maybe I have expression problems.. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**
For iOS you need to read those bytes in reverse order for correct value. Plus you are incorrectly reading 24-bits (3 bytes) instead of just 16-bits (2 bytes). Or maybe you are extracting 2 bytes but somehow your bytes are getting an extra "zero" byte added at the end??

You could try having an `OR` check inside an `If` statement thats checks both Endian type equivalents. Since where Android = **3** would become iOS = **768**, you can try:

```
if (orient_val == 3 || orient_val == 768) 
{ /* do whatever you do here */ }
```

PS: `1==256`  `2==512` `3==768` `4==1024` `5==1280` `6==1536` `7==1792` `8==2048`, `9==2304`

**long version:**
Android processors typically read bytes as **Little Endian**. Apple processors read bytes as **Big Endian**. Basically one type is read right-to-left, the other, is left-to-right. Where **Android** has `ABCD` that becomes in **iOS** as `DCBA`.

Some pointers:

- Your **3** as (2 bytes) in **Lil' E** is written `00`+`03`... but in
  **Big E** it's written `03`+`00`.
- Problem is, if you dont adapt and just read that `03 00` as though it's still **LE** then you get **768**.
- Worst still, somehow you are reading it as `03 00 00` which gives you
  that **196608**.
- Another is `06 00 00` giving you **393216** instead of reading `60 00` for **1536**.
- Fix your code to drop the extra `00` byte at the end.

You were lucky on Android cos I suspect it wants 4 bytes instead of 2 bytes. So that `00 00 06` was being read as `00 00 00 06` and since `x000006` and `x00000006` mean the same thing=`6`.

Anyways to fix this normally you could just tell AS3 to consider your Jpeg bytes as Big Endian but that would now fix iOS but then break it on Android.

**A quick easy solution** is to check if the number you got is bigger than 1 digit, if it is then you assume app is running on iOS and try reverse-ordering to see if now the result is 1 digit. So..

Note: option B shown in code is risky because if you have wrong numbers anyway you'll get a wrong result. You know computers.. "`bad input = bad output; do Next();`"

```
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

var Orientation_num:uint = 0;
var jpeg_bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); //holds entire JPEG data as bytes
var bytes_val:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); //holds byte values as needed

Orientation_num = 2048; //Example: Detected big number that should be 8.

if (Orientation_num > 8 ) //since 8 is maximum of orientation types
{
    trace ("Orientation_num is too big : Attempting fix..");

    //## A: CORRECT.. Either read directly from JPEG bytes
    //jpeg_bytes.position = (XX) - 1; //where XX is start of EXIF orientation (2 bytes)
    //bytes_val = jpeg_bytes.readShort(); //extracts the 2 bytes

    //## B: RISKY.. Or use the already detected big number anyway
    bytes_val.writeShort(Orientation_num);

    //Flip the bytes : Make x50 x00 become x00 x50
    var tempNum_ba : ByteArray = new ByteArray(); //temporary number as bytes
    tempNum_ba[0] = bytes_val[1];
    tempNum_ba[1] = bytes_val[0];

    //tempNum_ba.position = 0; //reset pos before checking
    Orientation_num = tempNum_ba.readShort(); //pos also MOVES forward by 2 bytes

    trace ("Orientation_num (FIXED) : " + Orientation_num);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am using this class [Exif Class](https://github.com/tmaiaroto/agile_uploader/blob/master/lib/com/patrickshyu/ExifReader.as) in case this changes anything.

Comment: Yesterday I managed to test it so many time and it seems that the numbers 393216, 196608, 524288, 65536 returned by iOS are constant, so I did if (orient_val == 3 || orient_val == 196608) and everything went smooth..

Comment: But still you detailed answer if very nice.. Thank you

Comment: OK glad it worked but I just did an edit. Whichever one works for you is okay. Later you can still read the other answer by clicking the **[edited](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27395534/3)** text in middle.